# reduce Makefile redundancy

Tags: c, makefile

I currently have a Makefile that deals with small set of files that can be built separately. The naming scheme and structure is the same for each set of 3 files; header, implementation, and test driver. I'm going to have about 4 more groups like the 3 below.

What are some less redundant ways to structure this Makefile, to avoid the repetitive nature of each group?

```
flextest: flex_test.o  flex.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o  $@  $^
flex_test.o: flex_test.c flex.o minunit.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c  $<
flex.o: flex.c flex.h debug.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c  $<

skiptest: skip_test.o  skip.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o  $@  $^
skip_test.o: skip_test.c skip.o minunit.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c  $<
skip.o: skip.c skip.h debug.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c  $<

dynatest: dyna_test.o dyna.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o  $@  $^
dyna_test.o: dyna_test.c dyna.o minunit.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c  $<
dyna.o: dyna.c dyna.h debug.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c  $<
```

Comment: Are you using GNU make, or another implementation? And do you need your makefile to work on other implementations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you and anyone else who uses this makefile are using GNU make, you can take a ton of shortcuts. Something like this should work:

```
%test: %_test.o %.o
%_test.o: minunit.h
%.o: %.h debug.h

all: flextest skiptest dynatest
```

Comment: I can rename, but what would be in conflict with the current naming scheme?

Comment: For example, `flex_test.o` matches both `%_test.o` and also `%.o`. I don't know off-hand how make handles rules that overlap like that. You could try it as-written and see if I got it right. :-)

Comment: It'll work; GNUMake chooses the rule that requires the shortest stem, i.e. the one where `%` matches `flex` rather than `flex_test`.